# Check wether an user has used hangout before

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-hangouts

Is there a way to check wether an user has used hangout before via API? I need it to build a report and promoting hangout within the organisations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no API that tracks this.

Depending on your exact needs, you might be able to run an organizational hangout app when they start it, triggered by the start button, which would report they're using the app... but this isn't foolproof (it would ignore hangouts started via calendar, for example).